# What is the appropriate way to make a line break in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I make a line break in a proper way in Javascript?

I was going through the [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) site for a solution and they came up with this:

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello \
Dolly.";
</script>
```

I tried this code in their `Tryit Editor v2.1` provided in their site but this code doesn't work properly there. In the output, everything's ok, except there is actually **no line break** between the strings `'Hello'` and `'Dolly'`.

I've also checked this code in my `Netbeans 8.0.1` ide and encountered the exact same problem here as well.

I have no idea where the problem is. Or is this not the right way to make a line break? If so, what is the right way to make a line break? Is there a better approach? Please help.

My browser is Mozilla Firefox ver. 32.0.3

**Edit - 1:**

Thanks a lot to users @ahmadalbayati, @webeno and @TheProvost for providing me the solution. It has been fixed. However, I'd like to add that, apart from their solution, the following code:

```
<script>
    document.write("Hello <br/> Dolly.");
</script>
```

gives me the exact same output as well. The same, just instead of manipulating a specific `html` element, it's writing something to the whole `html`.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272623/how-to-insert-a-line-break-with-javascript

Comment: you have to know what you want. add "\n" or "<br/>"

Comment: I can add a "<br/>" in html. I want to do it using Javascript.

Comment: then do that: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello <br/> Dolly.";`

Comment: Ok. @ahmadalbayati ' s solution works, that's great! But I'd appreciate additional answers and far better methods, if exist. Also, a detailed explanation is welcome.

Comment: This is the only and best way to do it.

Comment: w3schools seems pretty much misleading nowadays. Too bad. :(

Comment: w3schools has improved but I would still avoid it [w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com)

Comment: The question does not say what it means by “doing” or “making” a line break. Apparently, the intent is to ask how to cause *in HTML* a line break in rendering; the issue of producing HTML with JavaScript is a separate issue, and rather trivial. And there are several ways to cause a line break in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purely going out from your example (doing this in `html`), the following should work:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello <br /> Dolly.";
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

**EDIT**: just mentioning @ahmadalbayati's name here who provided the answer first in a comment, though I have not seen that before posting this answer (probably didn't refresh the screen).

Comment: +1. Although originally answered by @ahmadalbayati a few seconds ago, but I'm accepting this as answer. Thanks dude. :)

Comment: i didn't see @ahmadalbayati's answer, just gave him credit now in an edit

Answer (score 5):

"\" allows you to have multiple lines that the browser can understand for the script. But it wont make a new line for the output. Do something like this to create a new line in the output.

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello <br/> Dolly.";
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry my friend, but your code doesn't give me the right output. It still has the problem of `'Hello'` and `'Dolly'` both being in the same line.

Comment: oh i forgot /n does not work for IE. <br> works though but webeno answered it first.

Comment: Well, @webeno was faster in giving the correct asnwer, so I'm taking his solution as answer. Nevertheless, I gave a +1 to you for your efforts and the way you explained it to me. Thanks a lot. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: \n doesn't make a new line on the screen, it doesn't work for any browser. Thought it does make a linebreak in the codes.

Comment: @TheProvost the proper way of doing this, to my view, would have been if you added `<br />` as an edit and either credited it to ahmadalbayati or myself...

Comment: @ahmadalbayati really? shoot probably getting my c# and javascript all messed up...lols tnx for the heads up bro..this is what i like about stack overflow. you always learn new things you thought you already knew :)