# How do I break line in HTML using a JavaScript script

Tags: javascript, html, chat

So I'm having a problem where my code doesn't want to break line even after I put the correct syntax

```js
oldchat = ''

var paragraph = document.getElementById("chat");

function SendMsg() {
  let x = document.getElementById("Username")
  let username = x.value
  let message = prompt();
  chat = (oldchat + "\n" + username + ": " + message)
  oldchat = chat;
  let Modifiedmessage = document.createTextNode("\n" + username + ":" + message)
  paragraph.appendChild(Modifiedmessage);
}
```

```html
<input id="Username">
<button onclick="SetUser()">Set Username</button>
<button onclick="SendMsg()">send message</button>
<br>
<div id="chat">

</div>
```

I was expecting my code to break line have it be like

```
VibingCat: Hi
User123: Hello there!
```

Comment: You can use css instead of html+javascript.

Comment: Breaks in HTML are `<br>`, not `\n`

Comment: how is it printing now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a line break with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272623/how-to-insert-a-line-break-with-javascript)

Comment: 1: use `const` where needed. 2. Avoid the use of `prompt()` use `<textarea>` instead. 3. avoid the use of HTML inline `on*` handlers, use addEventListener instead. 4. don't name your functions with sentence-case. It's not a Class. 5. Don't use a string to store your chat messages use a better data format like an Array and object to hold the username, time and message. 6 etc etc

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the tips im still learning JS so my coding isnt the best or cleanest

Answer (score 0):

\n is not a line break in HTML, but <br> Is.

```
chat = (oldchat + "<br>" + username + ": " + message)
paragraph.innerHTML = chat;
```

Also you don't need to create a new text node for the modified message in the SendMsg() function, as you are already adding HTML to the paragraph element.

EDIT: As @Roko C. Buljan **innerHTML will make you vulnerable to XSS attacks so don't use it.**
I'm keeping the answer in case someone had the same idea.

Comment: Congratulations, you just made yourself vulnerable to XSS attacks :)

Answer (score 0):

- you just need to use a bit of **CSS** like: `line-break: pre-wrap;` in order to interpret the `\n`
- to prevent XSS, use always `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`, or create text nodes instead of HTML.

```js
// DOM utility functions
const el = (sel, par) => (par || document).querySelector(sel);
const elNew = (tag, prop) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), prop);

// CHAT:

// Load old messages from DB?
const messages = [
  {username: "John", message: "Hi Anne!\nwhat's up?"},
  {username: "Anne", message: "Hey John!\nHow's going with JS?"},
];

const elUsername = el("#username");
const elMessage = el("#message");
const elSend = el("#send");
const elChat = el("#chat");

const printMessage = (msg) => {
  const elMsg = elNew("div", {
    className: "msg",
  });
  const elMsgUsername = elNew("div", {
    className: "msg-username",
    textContent: msg.username,
  });
  const elMsgText = elNew("div", {
    className: "msg-message",
    textContent: msg.message
  });
  elMsg.append(elMsgUsername, elMsgText);
  elChat.append(elMsg);
};

const sendMessage = () => {
  const username = elUsername.value.trim();
  const message = elMessage.value.trim();
  if (!username || !message) return;
  printMessage({username, message});
  elMessage.value = "";
};

elSend.addEventListener("click", sendMessage);

// Init: Print old messages:
messages.forEach(printMessage);
```

```css
* { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

#chat {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font: 1rem/1.3 sans-serif;
}

.msg {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.msg-username {
  color: #888;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.msg-message {
  white-space: pre-wrap; /* NOTICE THIS! */
}

#message {
  display: block;
  min-width: 20rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat"></div>
<input id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username..."><br>
<textarea id="message" placeholder="Type a message..."></textarea>
<button id="send" type="button">Send</button>
```

As you see from the above:

1. use `const` where needed
2. avoid the use of `prompt()` use `<textarea>` instead
3. avoid the use of HTML inline `on*` handlers, use `addEventListener()` instead. JS is supposed to be in one place, and that's the respective file or tag
4. don't name your functions with sentence-case. It's not a Class
5. don't use a string to store your chat messages use a better data format like an Array and object to hold the username, time and message
6. `trim()` your messages from whitespaces

Comment: damn not only dose this work better but it looks better as well thanks 